# Use join for three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables and I would like sum over values by month from three tables.

The structure of database:

```
1)costs_1

-id
-total
-updated_at(timestamp)

2)costs_2

-id
-total_1
-updated_at_1(timestamp)

3)costs_3
    -id
    -total_2
    -updated_at_2(timestamp)
```

Structure of result table: 1)total; 2)total_1; 3)total_2; 4)month

I have code that work for two tables, but don't know how to adapte it

```html
        SELECT t1.y year,
           t1.m month,
           COALESCE(t1.total, 0),
           COALESCE(t2.total, 0)
               
        FROM
        (
            SELECT YEAR(date_month) y, 
                   MONTH(date_month) m, 
                   SUM(total) total
            FROM market_costs
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_month), MONTH(date_month) 
        ) t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT YEAR(date_month) y, 
                   MONTH(date_month) m, 
                   SUM(total) total
            FROM general_costs
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_month), MONTH(date_month) 
        ) t2 ON t1.y = t2.y and t1.m = t2.m
        
           UNION
        
        SELECT t2.y year,
               t2.m month,
               COALESCE(t1.total, 0),
               COALESCE(t2.total, 0)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT YEAR(date_month) y, 
                   MONTH(date_month) m, 
                   SUM(total) total
            FROM market_costs
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_month), MONTH(date_month) 
        ) t1
        RIGHT JOIN
        (
            SELECT YEAR(date_month) y, 
                   MONTH(date_month) m, 
                   SUM(total) total
            FROM general_costs
            GROUP BY YEAR(date_month), MONTH(date_month) 
        ) t2 ON t1.y = t2.y and t1.m = t2.m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the 3 tables using `UNION ALL` then group the data:

```
SELECT
      YEAR(t1.date_month) y
    , MONTH(t1.date_month) m
    , SUM(t1.total) total
    , SUM(t1.total_1) total_1
    , SUM(t1.total_2) total_2
FROM (
      SELECT
            date_month
          , total
          , NULL as total_1
          , NULL as total_2
      FROM costs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            date_month
          , NULL as total
          , total_1
          , NULL as total_2
      FROM costs_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            date_month
          , NULL as total
          , NULL as total_1
          , total_2
      FROM costs_2
      ) t1
GROUP BY
      YEAR(t1.date_month)
    , MONTH(t1.date_month)
```

**added**

```
SELECT
      YEAR(t1.date_month) y
    , MONTH(t1.date_month) m
    , SUM(t1.total) total
    , SUM(t1.total_1) total_1
    , SUM(t1.total_2) total_2
FROM (
      SELECT
            date_month
          , total
          , NULL as total_1
          , NULL as total_2
      FROM costs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            date_month
          , NULL as total
          , total as total_1 -- changed
          , NULL as total_2
      FROM costs_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
            date_month
          , NULL as total
          , NULL as total_1
          , total as total_2  -- changed
      FROM costs_2
      ) t1
GROUP BY
      YEAR(t1.date_month)
    , MONTH(t1.date_month)
```

Comment: It's work, thanks! But how to use it if field total same in three tables like 'total', 'total', 'total'?) I get error.

Comment: simple, see **added** in answer aove

Comment: by the way: if you get an error supply the **complete** error message

Comment: okay)Thank you, it reall help me. You solution more short than my code above